# Re-render CSS after JS changes the HTML element's position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

I have a unique situation to address. Have 10 `div`s with each having an image on the left and a paragraph on the right. Now, I am using CSS `nth-child()` selector to switch the position of all the odd div's image on the left to show up on the right with Flex's order property.

A pen to illustrate the issue- https://codepen.io/rpmcmurphy/pen/dyNaRJw

The issue is when I use JS to reorder the parent `div`s, all 10 randomly, they take the `nth-child(odd)` with them, meaning two/three odd parents show up one after another. Here is a visual representation of what I am trying to achieve-

How they are on page load-

```
<div> // div 1
    <img src=""> <p>Hello</p>
<div>
.......
<div> // div 10
    <img src=""> <p>Hello</p>
<div>
```

What I am doing-

```
1. All 10 parent divs will rearrange randomly (using JS I am already doing that)
2. All the ODD `div`s will push the <IMG> to the right side (using flex's order property to do that)
```

Both of the tricks work individually. But when combined, this is how the page look like-

```
<div> // div 1
    <img src=""> <p>Hello</p>
<div>
<div> // div 2
    <p>Hello</p> <img src="">
<div>
<div> // div 3, previously div 10 before JS rearranged it, for example
    <img src=""> <p>Hello</p>
<div> // div 4
    <img src=""> <p>Hello</p>
<div>
.......
```

With the flex order set for all the odd divs, when JS is taking, for example, original `div` 10 into `div` 3 right above, it should get the CSS I wrote for the ODD child and set the `img` tag to the right side, as it was number 10 originally (EVEN), now JS made it number 3 (ODD). It doesn't pick up the new CSS as ODD, stays EVEN though it's switched by JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CSS, I think it's what you want.

```
.row:nth-child(odd) > div:nth-child(1) {
  order: 20 !important;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
.row:nth-child(odd) > div:nth-child(2) {
  order: 10 !important;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```